# Knex Can't add the results of a query to an object

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, knex.js

I am trying to make an object `hbsObject` to render for handlebars in express.
The object should contain a post and replies. I am using knex, express and postgresql.
The code:

```
app.get('/:id(\\d+)/', (req, res) => {
  let hbsObject = {};
  knex('post')
    .where('id', '=', req.params.id)
    .then(posts => {
      if (posts.length > 0) {
        hbsObject.post = posts;
        console.log(hbsObject); "returns the post inside of hbsObject"
      } else {
        res.status(404).render('404');
      }
    });
  console.log(hbsObject); //returns "{}"
  knex('reply')
    .where('original_id', '=', req.params.id)
    .then(replies => {
      if (replies.length > 0) {
        hbsObject.replies = replies;
        res.render('one', hbsObject);
      } else {
        res.status(404).render('404');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: you should use `await`

Comment: then i get ```SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules```

Comment: `async (req, res) => {`